# How to format date field to ISO 8601 format?

Tags: apex, api, datetime, date

I need to have a Date field send in an apex API callout in the format that matches this format `"2019-05-28T19:40:36+00:00"`

I currently have the following:

```
Datetime startDate = datetime.newInstance(intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c.year(),intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c.month(),intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c.day());
String startDate2 = startDate.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ');
System.debug('StartDate: '+startDate2);
```

However this produces `StartDate: 2020-07-27T04:00:00:000+0000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you format to GMT you know that the timezone offset will always be 00:00. Hence you can simply do:

```
Datetime startDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(2020, 7, 21, 20, 40, 00);
String startDate2 = startDate.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss') + '+00:00';
System.debug('StartDate: ' + startDate2);
```

(That I create a Datetime instance with newInstanceGmt was just for my benefit; construct it how you need.)